# Simple url Htaccess Redirection + youtube

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Need help in forwarding below url with .htaccess rules

https://www.example.com/watch?v=yzwRsQ7rR-o

forward to

https://www.example.com/?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzwRsQ7rR-o

I've following exisitng rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this redirect with query string

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^watch
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} v=([A-Za-z0-9-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I tried your rewirte rules but, not working for some reason.